# Android Studio Build tab not showing build app bundle

Tags: java, android-studio, build, android-app-bundle

I have a project and I want to export the project to an `.aab` file. But when i go to build the option to do that isn't there.
Here is an image to show you what the problem is that I am facing:

[image]

It is a java android project, but the option to export to an `.aab` (as shown above isn't there). Do you have any idea how to fix this or how to get the option

This is how other poeple Build Tab looks inside android studio:

[image]

Comment: Have you already changed the build variant to release?

Comment: If this does not work then use:  File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart